# How do I print the names and values of all variables defined IN MY SCRIPT?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am working on a script and it would really help me, in this context, if I could see a dump of all the script defined variable names and values. Here's an example:

```bsh
foo="1"
bar="2"

print_script_variables 

baz="3"

print_script_variables
```

This would output:

```
foo="1"
bar="2"

foo="1"
bar="2"
baz="3"
```

Does something like `print_script_variables` exist? I have a feeling parsing the scripts you are executing is a fools errand.

If this doesn't exist, I would just type out a bunch of `echo` commands by hand. That's kind of annoying, because I'd like move where put `print_script_variables` as I troubleshoot without having to worry about which variables go in and out of scope.

This is a bash script, but I use zsh in my terminal, so something that would work in both would be ideal.

Comment: `declare -p` would do that but also include environment variables inherited by the script

Comment: @muru if that's the best thing that exists, it's better than echoing everything by hand, right? That could be an answer, but I'm hoping there's a better one out there. Maybe I could create a script to remove the lines that are env variables.

Comment: `diff <(export) <(declare -p)` will output a *different* superset of variables, but I don't know of a way to get only the ones you want. It may be possible to build something out of these components.

Comment: You could also use something simple like `set | grep '^[a-z]'` if your variables by convention start with a lowercase character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to muru's reply, you could store the names of environment variables at the start to the script, and filter out the environment variables whenever the print_script_variables function is invoked. For a POSIX compliant way to do so, use the set utility to list all variables at the start of the script and store those in a temporary file. When the function print_script_variables is invoked, use diff to filter out the variables you don't need, i.e.,

```
# invoke at script start
set > /tmp/file1 # assuming /tmp/file1 is a safely generated temporary file
trap 'rm -f /tmp/file1' INT TERM HUP EXIT # delete the file on SIG{INT,TERM,HUP} and EXIT
print_script_variables() {
    # suppress lines unique to file1 and lines present in pipe (set output)
    # that it outputs only lines added to file1, i.e. new variables
    set | comm -13 /tmp/file1 - # edited; thanks to Martin for helping to save an extra file;
}
variable=20
print_script_variables
```

## Edit

As you need a way to automatically execute the first line, you can use the [dot (or source)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/dot.html) utility for automatically executing the line at the start of a script. You should store the first line and the function definition in a file, say `print_script_variables`:

```
set > /tmp/file1
trap 'rm -f /tmp/file1' INT TERM HUP EXIT
print_script_variables() {
    set | comm -13 /tmp/file1 -
}
```

and source that file at the start of your script like so

```
. print_script_variables

variable=20
print_script_variables()
```

Comment: That's extremely clever and simple. Would there be any way of automatically executing that first line when any script is started? That way, I wouldn't have to refer back to the implementation of an exported `print_script_variables` if I want to remember how to use it. (This might be a really stupid ask, sorry.)

Comment: I was going to offer what turns out to be a very similar suggestion. I would create a function "dump variables()` that took a parameter. "init" would initialise the temporary file, ""print" or nothing would dump the differences, "end" would delete the temporary file. But fundamentally the solution is the same so little point offering it as a separate answer. +1

Comment: @DanielKaplan I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: I've not yet tried it out, but would something along the lines of `set | comm -13 /tmp/file1 -` work and save the extra temporary file?

Comment: @Martin yeah, it seems much better than creating /tmp/file2, thanks, answer has been edited

Comment: I think `FILE1=<(set)` could prevent file1? Perhaps that could be wrapped in an if statement that only runs if `$FILE1` doesn't already exist? That edit is another clever idea :)

Comment: @DanielKaplan unfortunately process redirection is a non-POSIX feature so it wouldn't be supported across all machines. even more unfortunate is that the `trap` utility isn't a feature in POSIX anymore, so you can't automatically remove the temp file if the script is interrupted.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Hey! It's actually still possible to use trap in POSIX, just that they changed the POSIX specification website to a PDF-like format using anchors from the original normal WWW document and worst of all, the search engine they provide is **bad**. I've updated the answer to delete the file when the script itself (the running script) receives any one of death signals. The only thing you'll need is an alternative to the mktemp utility to generate a random filename in /tmp/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that uses grep to filter out inherited vars.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Store names of inherited variables (by definition, exported)
readonly GREP_FILTERS=$(env | cut -d= -f1 | xargs printf " -e %s" )

print_script_vars() {
  declare -p | grep -v -E $GREP_FILTERS
}
```

Use *declare -p* if you want to see all shell variables, or *env* if only interested in exported vars.

Answer (score 0):

Improved code by Adam Mlodzinski

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Store names of inherited variables (by definition, exported)
readonly GREP_FILTERS=$(env | cut -d= -f1 | xargs printf " -e %s" )

print_script_vars() {
  declare -p | grep -v -E $GREP_FILTERS | sed 's/declare -[^ ]\{1,2\} //' | grep =
}

variable=20


print_script_vars
```

Comment: Please suggest this as an edit to Adam Mlodzinski’s answer (and explain how it improves that).

Comment: @StephenKitt I have a meta question. If DenisVS edits *this* answer to explain how it improves on Adam Mlodzinski's, would that justify its separate existence; as far as I know, I wouldn't be notified of the edit so I'd be missing out.

Comment: A comment to the edited answer should produce a notification. OP should always be notified of that AFAIK.