# Why should I care about POSIX if I'm writing bash scripts?

Tags: shell-script, posix, gnu

Looking for suggestions/edits I can make to this question to get it reopened. A lot of these answers seem objective to me and they are the type of answers I'm looking for.

---

I've read four articles about POSIX and haven't been able to find an answer. Now I know what POSIX *is*, I already knew what standards were, but I'm still not sure why the POSIX standard remains relevant today. One of the three articles I read was [an interview of Richard Stallman](https://opensource.com/article/19/7/what-posix-richard-stallman-explains). In it, he says

> **Seth**: Are POSIX-compliant free software projects easier to port to other Unix-like systems?
>
> **RMS**: I suppose so, but I decided in the 1980s not to spend my time on porting software to systems other than GNU. ...
>
> **Seth**: Is POSIX important to software freedom?
>
> **RMS**: At the fundamental level, it makes no difference. However, standardization ...  helped us advance more quickly towards ... free software. *That was achieved in
> the early 1990s*... [emphasis mine]

His answers are colored by a GNU point of view, but it seems he's answering my question with, "POSIX is no longer relevant"?

Here's something more concrete to explain why I'm interested in this in the first place: [In this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696772/101311), I suggested using process redirection `<(command)`. A reply said, "unfortunately process redirection is a non-POSIX feature so it wouldn't be supported across all machines."

I guess I was assuming that the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`. Since process redirection is a feature of bash, wouldn't that mean any system with bash would be portable? [And according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), bash "has been used as the default login shell for most Linux distributions."

Whereas, [this article says](https://linuxhint.com/is_linux_posix_compliant/), "For now, Linux is not POSIX-certified due to high costs, except for the two commercial Linux distributions Inspur K-UX [12] and Huawei EulerOS [6]. Instead, Linux is seen as being mostly POSIX-compliant."

So, I *think* the goal of POSIX is portability, but, at least in my experience, my scripts would be *more* portable if they worked in bash and ignored POSIX than the other way around.

To reiterate my question, *why* should any scriptwriter spend time concerning themselves with POSIX compliance?

Comment: Process substitution isn't even supported on every system **running Bash**, so *part* of the premise here doesn't hold up.

Comment: It's the same conflict with any standard (HTML, C++, …): To expand possibilities, you lose portability. For your personal projects, I recommend to think twice whether a small advantage is worth binding yourself to a special tool like clumsy old bash. The answer *can* be yes, but I suggest to always keep in mind what is standard and what is *bashism*. After years of bash usage I needed too long to get rid of bad habits when I had to write `dash` scripts for fast system start, `ash` scripts on small busybox systems and completely switching to `zsh` for different non-POSIX features.

Comment: not every system is a GNU system, and many do not ship with `bash`. even for those that do, it may not be the default shell for system services, so scheduled execution may not always work as intended

Comment: oof, just wrote that answer and then scrolled up to see @Philippos's comment had pretty much all of my points already, oh well.

Comment: What type of things do you do with the scripts that you write? Are your scripts ever redistributed to the wider Unix (not just Linux) community? Do you ever work with fixing/modifying software that other people have written, possibly for the sake of creating upstream patches, or for packaging for your current favorite Unix system?

Comment: You shouldn't. /thread

Comment: @MichaelHomer can you elaborate?

Comment: @Philippos `...switching to zsh for different non-POSIX features` Isn't this another reason to ignore POSIX when making decisions? It doesn't help me in this situation, does it? `I suggest to always keep in mind *what is standard* and what is bashism` At face value, this makes sense, but I still can't figure out how knowing POSIX helps me as much as knowing a common shell.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Sorry, my explanation was probably worded too short. If I know POSIX, but I choose to use an `xxsh` feature in my script, I mark it as such by a comment. If I (or someone else) does port it one fine day, such a comment saves lots of searching effort. You need to know the standard for this.

Comment: Process substitution requires operating-system support that is not present on all systems (because it’s non-POSIX…). Bash will report an error if you try to use it on one that doesn’t, so it’s not the case that “any system with bash would be portable” (even before getting to version differences that are regrettably still relevant).

Comment: In relation to your original question, though, which was seeking something for specifically Bash (and zsh) scripts on your machine… it is hard to see how that goal in the answer you received was constructive or relevant and I would have used the process substitution.

Comment: @Philippos And what about *zshims* ?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Process substitution (like a few other bash features) is disabled if bash is run under the name `sh`. So even on systems where /bin/sh is bash, it won't be available if someone runs your script with `sh scriptname` (this overrides the shebang line), or in something like a `system()` call from a program, or...

Comment: @IsaaC Obviously the same, that's why I exlicitly mentioned "different non-POSIX features" in zsh and used `xxsh` as a placeholder for any shell that expands the standard. You always need to keep in mind what incompatibilities you introduce, even if `zsh` features may be more tempting to leave the standard.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I did some preliminary googling of my own and fell short: what's an OS that doesn't have process substitution but *is* POSIX compliant? I'm not trying to give you the 3rd degree here. No need to spend effort researching this, I just thought you might have an answer off the top of your head.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, "process substitution" isn't an OS feature. It's a _shell_ feature, and there are multiple ways to implement it. The _most efficient_ way requires something like Linux's `/dev/fd/` support, but it can be built on top of named pipes, so any OS that's properly POSIX-y (as [named pipes _are_ POSIX-defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifo.html)) can have a shell build process substitution on top of it. Indeed, bash falls back to the named-pipe approach when compiled on an OS that don't support addressability for anonymous file descriptors.

Comment: @ilkkachu, ...I'm pretty sure Michael is wrong.

Comment: I’m just relaying what’s documented for process substitution in the Bash manual, which specifically calls out that it isn’t supported on all systems. I agree with ilkkachu that it *ought* to be available on any fully-conformant system (POSIX also requires writable /tmp), I just don’t expect it to work anywhere that Bash does because it’s explicitly documented not to.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, yep. I guess I should have considered something more obviously non-POSIX to begin with. FWIW, there's some mentions of MinGW and Cygwin in Bash's `./configure`, so I guess it's at least been possible to compile Bash on those. And I wouldn't be exactly surprised if named pipes were an issue on Windows... Thanks, and sorry for the noise!

Comment: @MichaelHomer, bash has been ported to some non-POSIX-compliant systems, so in that context it makes sense; anywhere that doesn't have `mkfifo` will have a bad day.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the RMS point of view is: *I'm only interested in standards as long as the help users to migrate to GNU, but I don't like standards that help users to free themselves from GNU*?

Comment: @Philippos I'm not interpreting it that way, though clearly, I'm the most ignorant person in this conversation. The way I interpreted it is like this: "POSIX serve**d** a very valuable  purpose. It prevented UNIX from fragmenting to the point where users had to form camps, locking them to a specific OS/distro. That was achieved in the 1990s, so I don't worry about POSIX anymore, because it's become more pedantic than pragmatic."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need to care if you *know* you're only going to use some particular shell that's not limited to just the POSIX features.

But, there's still a chance you'll end up having to use something else, and in that case, having an idea about the non-standard features might help. Maybe you worked on Linux all your life, but then a new $DAYJOB drops you on the shell of some completely different system.

Not that it's just non-Linux systems though. Embedded/small systems might have just Busybox, and its default `ash`-based shell is closer to plain POSIX sh than Bash. (Busybox also has another shell, `hush`, which I'm not that familiar with. I doubt it's a Bash clone either. Anyway, on small systems, having a smaller shell is usually desired, and that might well mean less features.) Also, Debian (and hence, Ubuntu) famously cared too: since Bash is rather slow and shell scripts were used a lot for system startup before systemd came along they changed the default `/bin/sh` to Dash, another ash-based shell.
(See e.g. [an LWN article on that](https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/) and [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) on Ubuntu's wiki.)

Then there's also some cases where doing the POSIX thing just doesn't cost anything, since the features are equivalent. I admit, the ones I can think of are rather simple, e.g. using `[ a = b ]` instead of `[ a == b ]`, or `i=$((i + 1))` instead of `((i++))`. Anyway, cases like that exist, and esp. using `==` seems rather common, with no benefit. (`[[ .. ]]` vs. `[ .. ]` is a bit different though, they have actual differences.)

That's not to say e.g. local variables, arrays, process substitutions, and the string replace and slice expansions should never be used! Quite the contrary, I think they are *very* useful when needed. Just that it helps to be aware they don't work in every shell in the world. Or worse, they don't work identically.

All that said, if we consider the answers here on unix.SE, it should be noted that the site title says "Unix & Linux", and it is called `unix.stackexchange.com`, not `linux.stackexchange.com`, so keeping the non-Linux systems in mind is somewhat relevant. Also, I guess a bunch of the long-time users are pedants like that. ;)

If you're happy to leave the POSIX chains and rely on having Bash, you might also want to consider using zsh. It's even less POSIX-compatible, which actually makes it a lot saner in many ways.

Comment: nice answer. I actually use zsh by default, but at this moment, I tend to write my scripts in bash.

Comment: "some completely different system" would be MacOS, which switched to `zsh`. Windows scripting would be done in PowerShell, which is entirely not POSIX-like. I.e. `$i++` and `if ($a -eq $b) `.  But `zsh` will handle `((i++))` just fine. The intersection of zsh and bash is much, much bigger than POSIX.

Comment: macOS switch to `zsh` as the default *user* shell. An ancient (but otherwise POSIX-mostly-compliant) version of `bash` remains the system shell.

Comment: @MSalters, or it might be a FreeBSD installation without Bash. Or something else entirely. Sure, we can list them all, but that's hardly the relevant point here. Yes, Bash and zsh mutually support a bunch of non-POSIX features, but zsh has some straight up incompatibilities with the POSIX shell, something that Bash at least tries to avoid. I'm not getting your point there.

Comment: @MSalters, ...that intersection is in no small part things that they both copied from ksh. :)

Comment: Caveat re: moving to zsh: Back in the mid-2000s, I tried that route... and discovered I was getting into bad habits that resulted in buggy code whenever I _did_ need to target a more POSIX-y shell. I think my takeaway from this is that I prefer my non-POSIX languages to not even _smell_ POSIX-y, to avoid cross contamination of finger memory.

Comment: "But, there's still a chance you'll end up having to use something else" In your opinion, is that likely or unlikely? I also am having difficulty figuring out how many unix/non-linux OS's out there don't have bash as an option. FreeBSD doesn't come with it, but it can be installed.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, think about embedded systems -- bash is a lot larger than dash or ash just in terms of executable size. Sometimes that matters, which is why you're a lot more likely to see busybox ash on your cell phone or router (if you're lucky; if you're unlucky, then you get one of the handbuilt, bug-filled, non-POSIX-y shells that shipped with older versions of Busybox before they cut over to ash).

Comment: @DanielKaplan, well, I did mention the two environments that I could think of: embedded installations and non-Linux systems. How likely someone is to encounter them is harder to guess. I suppose it depends on the work they do and how likely they're to change jobs to a sufficiently different area... So, idunno.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the option of writing a shell script using non-POSIX features, then you also have the option of writing your script in a language *other than* the family of Bourne shell languages. All such languages have better ergonomics than shell, in most cases *much* better ergonomics (the only exceptions I have ever encountered are Tcl and csh).

Therefore: If you don't need the portability—if it's not a relevant design constraint that `/bin/sh` is the only script interpreter that you can be *sure* exists on anything that pretends to be a Unix—then *don't write a shell script*.  Use one of those more ergonomic languages instead.

Comment: Every day you can read some questions here that can be answered with a minimalistic shell script with two commands connected by a pipe. I can hardly imagine any language with better ergonomics on such problems.

Comment: @Philippos Sure, but you don't need any non-POSIX features for such scripts.

Comment: Something like `(#i)*.jpg` or `./**/*.c` is non-POSIX, but can be quite handy (not necessary, of course) in simple scripts. But I'm going off-topic.

Comment: @Philippos how does one go about learning that `(#i)*.jpg` or `./**/*.c` is non-POSIX? Is that by running bash in POSIX only mode and bumping into problems?

Comment: @DanielKaplan I used to learn a lot of things from reading other scripts. When getting rid of `bash` in an embedded system for legal reasons, I learned the hard way what parts are not portable. Ever since I started checking unknown syntax in man pages, so I learn what is out of standard (and by the way I get deeper knowledge on the syntax mechanics).

Answer (score -4):

I have to admit that I have never even thought of POSIX when writing bash scripts; I would expect this to have been taken into account (or not) when writing the code for bash; your bash scripts should work on any system where bash is available.

In my experience, POSIX is very helpful when writing portable code in C or C++ (or other compiled languages); you can even find POSIX compliant libraries in Windows. Or you could 20 years ago, they may have removed them since, but I remember fighting a hopeless battle with getting certain things to work with Windows-only functions in C++, but as soon as I started using POSIX functions, it just worked.

When it comes to interpreted languages, like Java, Python or bash, they have already been ported to many different platforms, so your code should just work on all of them, except perhaps for the idiosyncrasies of Windows path names and that sort of things.

Comment: POSIX does describe C libraries, but POSIX _also_ describes the shell syntax and required commands. The latter is clearly what the question is about, and discussion of C(++) largely irrelevant.